# Getting an item's field information (FieldInformation) without actually downloading

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I noticed that `Copy.asmx` [`GetItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.copy.getitem%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method retrieves useful information about the item/file, but also actually downloads it.

I've looked through all the web service and I can't find anything that would let me fetch that info without downloading it.

Is there such a method anywhere ?

Here is how I use the method for the moment:

```
FieldInformation[] fieldInfo;
byte[] fileStream;

var t = _copyClient.GetItem(fullUrl, out fieldInfo, out fileStream);
```

Is there any way to tell the method to trash the output of the fileStream and not download it ? I tried passing `null` or `out null` of course the method did not like it...

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I was able to fetch some more metadata using `GetVersions` from `versions.asmx` but I still don't get all the field information I'm looking for though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be using [`Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.Aspx) for this. I had no idea SP2010+ offered such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage [Lists.GetList Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlist%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to return a schema for the specified list and afterwards to extract fields information from a List schema.

The below example demonstrates how to extract and print fields information (JavaScript):

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetList",
  listName: "Documents",
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("Fields > Field").each(function() {
      var $node = $(this);
      console.log( "Type: " + $node.attr("Type") + " StaticName: " + $node.attr("StaticName") );
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: That's useful. Thanks. Now I know what are the fields that can be used for files uploaded using that view. But that does not tell me the values for these fields for files uploaded using this view (ie: files in `http://server/view/folder`).